# Como mandar um parâmetro através de um iframe para um pagina em outro servidor?

Tags: php, html5

Preciso de uma ajuda tenho uma página em um servidor X e preciso pegar uma outra página do servidor Y. Tentei em `ajax` e não consegui então tive que usar o `iframe`, porém preciso passar um parâmetro para a página destino do servidor Y e não está dando certo?

Abaixo seguem os códigos:

**Pagina do Servidor X origem**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set("display_errors", 0 );
    session_start();

    $perfil = $_SESSION['perfil'];
    echo $perfil;
?>
<br>
<iframe 
    style="border: 0;"
    src="https://172.20.220.50/webservice/listaRetorno.php?perfil=teste"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

**Pagina do servidor Y que retorna no iframe do código acima:**

```
// $perfil = $_POST['perfil'];  
$perfil = $_GET['perfil'];  
echo $perfil;
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente voce precisara de respostas sincronas, por isso o mais indicado e fazer a conversa entre as duas aplicacoes por meio de um protocolo (de preferencia ajax) com retorno tipado (por exemplo json).

Porque voce nao conseguiu por exemplo fazer um simples $.post('outroservidor') e pegar o resultado ?

Comment: ele provavelmente não conseguiu com ajax por causa do CORs, o que é questão de segurança.

Comment: ainda assim deve haver possibilidades melhores do que um iframe, claro, dependendo do nivel de capacidade de alteracoes que ele tem no servidor

Comment: Eu não disse que não há, até mesmo via Ajax se resolver o CORs vai funcionar, eu apenas responde a sua duvida "Porque voce nao conseguiu por exemplo fazer um simples" com uma probabilidade. Sendo servidores diferentes o problema geralmente é CORs, então o servidor que tentou acessar deve permitir isto.